# Windows 8.1 SOE creation and capture

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I trying to find information on Win 8.1 SOE creation/capture and wondering if anybody has ever done this and if there were any issues.

I've done it before with Windows 7, the process was:

- Build the SOE as I wanted it
- Create an image with clonezilla in case I missed something and had to
  go back
- Sysprep
- Network boot to Windows Deployment Services
- Capture Image.
- (The answer file was previously created)

With my new company we are using Altiris, I'm not familiar with it, and most of the SOE(Win 7) deployment is done via custom built USBs(created before I arrived) so the process isn't the same as before.

My plan is to 
 - Build the SOE as I want
 - Create an image with clonezilla in case I missed something and need
   to go back
 - Sysprep
 - Capture image using imagex booted from a USB
 - Create an answer file

Has anyone done this before? Is the process going to be the same? Is there anything I should look out for? Is there anything I'm missing? We recently got some Surface Pro 3 for a few users and there's probably more to come further down the line. I'd like not to have to configure each individually.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I was decided I couldn't afford to risk bricking one of the devices and ended up leaving the standard image on those ones and just installing the software needed. For anyone looking for more information I ended up finding some useful information online.

[Surface-Pro-3-Deployment-Administration-Guide-EN.pdf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=45292) and 
[Deploy Windows to Surface Pro 3 using Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2014/07/15/deploy-windows-to-surface-pro-3-using-microsoft-deployment-toolkit.aspx)